# Grunt Read json file and push field into another json file

Tags: json, gruntjs

I'm trying to read data from bower.json and push into an existing json file for my project

```
var mapping = grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json');
var map = grunt.file.readJSON('other.json);
```

How can I push it into the other file ? I have already tried push() and write()
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hard copy one json file to another you could use something like:

```
  var mapping = grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json');//read in the current
  grunt.file.write("other.json", JSON.stringify(mapping, null, 2));
```

Or if you wanted to set a certain field in other.json to be the same as bower.json:

```
  var mapping = grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json');//read in bower
  var map = grunt.file.readJSON('other.json');//read in other
  map["version"] = mapping["version"]; //copy mapping version to map version
  grunt.file.write("other.json", JSON.stringify(map, null, 2)); //save other.json
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose the second solution